# Determine the image of $ A=\{z=x+iy \in \Bbb C$ | $y=2x \}$ through T.

Tags: complex-analysis, linear-transformations

I have the the following linear transformation:

$$T(z) = \frac{(-\frac 13 -i\frac 23)z - \frac i2}{\frac z2 -1}$$
where $z \in \Bbb C$

I have to determine the image of $ A=\{z=x+iy \in \Bbb C$ | $y=2x \}$ through T.

Then I know that $z$ is of the type $z=x+2xi$.
What should I do ?
Do I have to calculate $T(x+2xi)$ ? I don't know

Comment: First, notice that $T$ is certainly not linear: just see that $T(0)\neq 0$, which is impossible for a linear function. About your question, yes, you need to find $T(x+2xi)$. Just as the set $A$ is described by $y=2x$, which is a relation between real and imaginary parts of $z$, you have to describe each $w\in T(A)$ by relating the real and the imaginary parts of $w$

Comment: oops, sorry.
so the solution of the exercise is simply: $T(x+2xi)=\frac {(-\frac 13 -i\frac 23)(x+2xi) - \frac i2}{ \frac{x+2xi}{2}-1}$ ? Don't I have to do anything else?

Comment: You have to multiply numerator and denominator by the complex conjugate of the denominator, getting $T(x+2xi)=X+iY$ then separate real and imaginary parts $X=..., Y=...$ and recognize on this form the parametric equations of a circle.

Comment: I don't understand...

Comment: Jean Marie is telling you that that $x \in \mathbb R \mapsto T(x+2xi) \in \mathbb C$ paramatrises a circle in the complex plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments the function $T$ is clearly not a linear map since it doesn't verify $T(0)  \neq 0.$
We have  $$ A = \{ x+ 2xi  : x \in \mathbb R  \}.$$ Therefore at $z = x+2ix $ we have

$$ T(x+2xi) =  \frac{-10x^2-18x}{15x^2-12x+12}+i \frac{6+13x-20x^2}{15x^2-12x+12}$$

Let $X = X(x)$ be the real part and $Y = Y(x)$ the imaginary part. Then $x \mapsto (X,Y)$ is a paramatrisation of $C\setminus\{(-2/3,-4/3)\}$ where $C$ is a conic. You can check that that $C$ is a circle with the following equation
$$ C\equiv (X+\frac{19}{24})^2 + (Y+\frac{1}{4})^2 = \frac{685}{576}.$$
Seeing this circle has a subset of the complex plane then we have

$$ T(A) = C \setminus \{\frac{-2}{3}+i \frac{-4}{3}\}.$$